# Android build output gives [HILT] only

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use room with hilt but it gives me just that output
I added all needed annoatations to fragments, activities , viewmodels and my application class.And I add dependencies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck your hilt dependencies I was facing the same issue it got solved after updating it.[here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#kts)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most times this issue occurs, it gets solved by just doing a Build > Clean Project, which deletes and re-generates the Hilt classes. If that does not work, check your hilt dependencies.